# Why when trying to create new XNA 4.0 project in c# i see only 4 templates?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xna, xna-4.0

[image: XNA PROJECT]

In the original i should have 9 templates like it show in the official microsoft page:

[XNA 4.0 Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203928.aspx)

Comment: Its possible that this because vs2012 doesn't have much support for xna, have you tried using vs2010?

Comment: Try switching your .NET framework to 4.0.  You're showing .NET 4.5, which could be the problem.

Comment: Microsoft has stopped supporting XNA, so the 4.5 framework will have less options to choose from.

Comment: This solved it using xna 4.0 on vs 2012 pro. http://ryan-lange.com/xna-game-studio-4-0-visual-studio-2012/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft decided xna is obsolete. They now want you to use it only for Windows Phone games. It's because xna works with Dx 9.

You can still reference it within Win Forms projects but you won't be able to use the Content Pipeline.

An alternative is MonoGame. It's an open source implementation of xna. It even supports many different platforms including mobile ones.